# Passing a variable - Python

Tags: python, class, constructor

I am trying to figure out why I cannot pass a variable from a widget entry to a variable meant to be the username within a class of objects.

As written it throws the following error: TypeError: enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
class User:
    'a class to define users'
    def __init__(self, username, goal, contra, gender, weight):
        self.username = username
        self.goal = goal
        self.contra = contra
        self.gender = gender
        self.weight = weight

'Adds date and current weight to an array to track progress'
    #def weighIn[date, weight]:
    def setUser(self, username):
        self.username = string
def enter(self):
    global e1
    global string
    string = e1.get() 
    setUser()

namescreen = Tk.Tk()
namescreen.title("Current Exercise")

var = StringVar()
label = Label( namescreen, textvariable=var)
var.set("Hi! What is your name?")
label.pack()
usr = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(namescreen, textvariable=usr)
e1.pack()
b1 = tkinter.Button(namescreen, text ="Enter", command =enter)
b1.pack()


namescreen.bind('<Return>', enter)
namescreen.mainloop()
```

I have also tried adding newUser = User.**init**(self, "Default"...) and it tells me that self is not defined. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: looks like an indentation error, which makes `enter` a function but not a method of your object.

Comment: @Thomas did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your `enter` function you cant call `setUser()` without an instance of class `User` because it's a member function.

Second, you should include the `enter` function as a member function of class User. Then you need to create a User object and bind the button to `User.event` and not just `event`.

This code will run correctly though.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

class User:
    'a class to define users'
    def __init__(self, username, goal, contra, gender, weight):
        self.username = username
        self.goal = goal
        self.contra = contra
        self.gender = gender
        self.weight = weight

    'Adds date and current weight to an array to track progress'
    #def weighIn[date, weight]:
    def setUser(self, username):
        self.username = string
        print('Username is {}'.format(self.username))
    def enter(self):
        global e1
        global string
        string = e1.get() 
        self.setUser(string)

namescreen = Tk.Tk()
namescreen.title("Current Exercise")

user = User('','','','','')

var = Tk.StringVar()
label = Tk.Label( namescreen, textvariable=var)
var.set("Hi! What is your name?")
label.pack()
usr = Tk.StringVar()
e1 = Tk.Entry(namescreen, textvariable=usr)
e1.pack()
b1 = Tk.Button(namescreen, text ="Enter", command =user.enter)
b1.pack()


namescreen.bind('<Return>', user.enter)
namescreen.mainloop()
```